# How to make Graphviz's dot executable path available in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, graphviz

Please i am new to rails a i want to generate an ER diagram for my application, i found that using **rails-erd gem** was an option which depended on **Graphviz** i have install the Graphviz application but can't figure out a way to make it visible in my rails application. I get the following error each time i run `rake erd` in my rails application.

```
$ rails erd
rails aborted!
Unable to find GraphViz's "dot" executable. Please visit 
https://voormedia.github.io/rails-erd/install.html for installation 
instructions.
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => erd => erd:generate => erd:check_dependencies
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out!!!
the reason it is not working is because Graphviz is not been seen by rails.
To solve the above issue, i just included Graphviz to my class path, and restarted my system, after which it started working.

**The following steps needs to be taking:**

1. Download Graphviz for windows and install.
2. Add the path to dot.exe which is located at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin** to your class path.
3. Add the gem to your gem file.
4. Install `rails install gem rails-erd`.
5. Generate your er diagrams by simply typing `rails erd` and an **er** diagram would be generated in a pdf file **(erd.pdf)** would be generated in your project root directory.